# In JNI trying to pass a boolean argument through CallObjectMethod fails

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I am relatively new to Java and JNI.  I have a Java instance method 
void setState(Boolean done) and I am attempting to call it from C++ using JNI

```
tbuff = env->GetObjectClass(buff);
jmethodID setStatemid = env->GetMethodID(tbuff, "setState", "
(Ljava/lang/Boolean;)V");

if(setStatemid==0){
  return JNI_FALSE;
}

// Set the buffer to busy
env->CallObjectMethod(buff, setStatemid, true);
```

The call to CallObjectMethod() crashes. I've tried passing JNI_TRUE or JNI_FALSE as well. It seems if I pass false or JNI_FALSE I make it to the method but value passed is null. If I pass true the JVM crashes.  Based on this I am assuming I am not passing a Boolean object properly.

Any guidance appreciated

Comment: Any reason why calling CallObjectMethod, instead of CallVoidMethod?

Comment: Did you try checking whether there are any JNI Environment erros by using env->ExceptionCheck() ?

Comment: @Will_Panda How can he call `ExceptionCheck()` when there has already been a JVM crash?

Comment: @EJP Before the  CallObjectMethod to check whether there are any other exceptions.

Comment: @Will_Panda Well he got as far as calling `CallObjectMethod()`, with a non-zero `methodID`, which can only have happened if both the prior `GetObjectClass()` and `GetMethodID()` calls succeeded.

Answer (score 5):

*I know it's an old question but I see it has no right answer yet.*

You must use primitive type boolean that is mapped with "Z" (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html)

So your code should be something like this:

```
jmethodID setStatemid = env->GetMethodID(tbuff, "setState", "(Z)V");
```

Answer (score 4):

> Based on this I am assuming I am not passing a Boolean object properly.

You aren't passing a `Boolean` object at all. You are passing an integer or C++ `bool` or whatever it is that has the value `true`.

You need to pass a Java `Boolean`, not `true`: specifically, `Boolean.TRUE`, which you would have to access first via JNI.

Better still, redesign your `setState()` method to take `boolean` and pass `JNI_TRUE`.

And, as the method has void return type, you should be calling `CallVoidMethod(),` not `CallObjectMethod()`.

Comment: Thank you. That was it!  I was not aware of the difference between Boolean and boolean. I didn't realize they were two different types. As for the use of CallVoidMethod().  This code is part of some early prototyping and the signatures have been changing.  I will use the appropriate function. @Will_Panda I will also be checking for exceptions .  Thank you all for commenting.